# NullReferenceException testing dataset in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I have written a 3 layer web site which has singleton repository for accessing database. My repositories use dataset for connecting to and query from database.
I want to test the site using Visual Studio 2010 Test project but when I create TableAdapter of dataset in repository I got following error in test application:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

the code work correctly when I use repository from the inside of site but in test application I got that error.
one of my repositories which I got that error is follow:

```
public sealed class VehicleRepository
{
    private readonly int gateCode;
    private readonly VehicleTableAdapter vehicleSet;
    private readonly VehicleTypeTableAdapter vehicleTypeSet;
    private static VehicleRepository instance;

    private VehicleRepository()
    {
        var configureTable = new ConfigurationTableAdapter();
--->>>      var configuration = configureTable.GetData().ToList();
            if (configuration.Count == 0)
                throw new UserInterfaceException("some message");
            if (configuration.Count != 1)
                throw new UserInterfaceException("some message");
            gateCode = configuration[0].GateCode;
            vehicleSet=new VehicleTableAdapter();
            vehicleTypeSet=new VehicleTypeTableAdapter();
        }

    public static VehicleRepository GetInstance()
    {
        return instance ?? (instance = new VehicleRepository());
    }

    public Vehicle GetVehicleByPlaque(string plaque)
    {
        .....
    }

    private static Vehicle ConvertVehicleRowToVehicle(TransportCo.VehicleRow vehicleRow,TransportCo.VehicleTypeRow vehicleTypeRow)
    {
        ....
    }

    public void SaveOrUpdate(Vehicle vehicle)
    {
        ...
    }

    private static void UpdateVehicle(Vehicle vehicle)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

I got the error in the --->>> line.
does anyone know the problem?

Comment: What does `ConfigurationTableAdapter.GetData()` return?

Comment: It is like this: select * from Configuration

Comment: And you are _certain_ that something is returned?

Comment: yes the code works when I run it from default.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that if you break that line into two steps and look at what `GetData` returns, you'll see it is null.

Comment: Though, if it returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, the call of `ToList()` may trigger the exception within an iterator block.

Comment: Interesting, Oded.  Hadn't thought about that - but I wonder if there's anything "behind" that call when the test is run.  I suspect not.

Comment: this code works when I run it from inside of web site. I put some test object in default.aspx and run the code and it works. so the configureTable.GetData() is not null

Comment: @JGC- OK, yeah - I *get* that it runs fine in the website.  In your test though, is `configureTable.GetData()` returning something other than null?

Comment: yes I put manually a record in table and in running of site it returns that record and I think it should return that record in test mode too.

Comment: @JGC-Sorry, I'm confused.  Are you saying that it *does* return a non-null value in test or just that you believe it *should* do so.

Comment: I'm saying that it return non-null value in real running so it means that the function works correctly. But the problem is it does not show the same behavior in test. So in test mode running I got that exception

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3775/discussion-between-jgc-and-itsmatt)

Answer (score 0):

One Common catch ya with databases and test is that usually the connection string is stored in the configuration file of the web site. The web.config is usually not in play when executing the tests. That can easily lead to a scenario like the one you describe. So even though you know that it works in production it doesn't say anything about whether the connection is setup up correctly in test

Comment: @JGC you make sure that the connection string is correct in the configuration file for the _test_ project

Comment: the test project does not have any configuration file because it uses repository class and repository is in web site project and it uses website web.config for connection.

Comment: @JGC How have you verified that to be the case? and what test framework do you use?

Comment: I use default test framework of visual studio 2010 which make Test project near real project. I put the test code in Default.aspx and traced the code and it worked fine so the problem should be in test project

Comment: @JGC In that case you do indeed need to create a configuration file for your test project. Putting the test code in default.aspx does nothing to verify that the configuration of the test project is correct. On the contrary. That the test code works when executed in the context of the web site but not in the test project rules out _code_ problems and points to configuration issues. add a applicatoin configuration file to the test project and add the connection string to it